# Crystal Report Retain Zero

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report wherein the user ID is taken. Whenever I try to take it, all the zeroes before the number are being suppresssed.

```
Employee ID: 0011
```

becomes

```
Employee ID: 11
```

I tried customizing the object but still persisting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID's are to be formatted with leading zeros, you can use the format-argument of the `CStr`-function.

Create following formula-field:

```
CStr({Table.EmployeeID}, "0000")
```